# primitive roots problem. that integer n can never have exactly 26 primitive roots.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, primitive-roots

Show that no integer $n$ can have exactly 26 primitive roots.

I know that if $n$ has primitive roots then it has exactly $\phi(\phi(n))$ primitive roots.
I think the proof has to use contradiction. 
Suppose $n$ is an integer and has exactly 26 primitive roots then $\phi(\phi(n))=26$. 
How do I carry on and show that $\phi(\phi(n))$ is not 26. 
Please explain me.

Comment: Well can you solve $\phi(m) = 26$?

Comment: It is [apparently known](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nontotient) that there is no $m$ such that $\phi(m) = 26$.  I'm not sure, however, how one would prove that this is the case.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom: Isn't it fairly simple, by showing that there are no two prime numbers $p,q$ such that $(p+1)(q+1)=26$?

Comment: hint:when $4\not|\phi(m)$

Comment: @barakmanos you're right; I guess it's been a while.

Answer (score 4):

$\phi(m)=26$ is impossible.

We have for prime $p$, $\phi(p^a)=p^a-p^{a-1}=(p-1)\cdot p^{a-1}$.  Also $\phi$ is multiplicative (that is, for $\gcd(j,k)=1$, $\phi(jk)=\phi(j)\phi(k)$).

From these two facts, we have that $\phi(j)$ is even except for $\phi(1)=\phi(2)=1$.

Thus to have any hope of $\phi(m)=26$, we'd need $m=p^a$ for some prime $p$ and positive integer $a$.  Then $p-1$ would have to be a factor of $26$: namely $1, 2, 13$, or $26$.  Then $p$ would have to be $2$ or $3$ (the other two possibilities don't yield prime values for $p$.  But you can easily check that neither $\phi(2^a)$ nor $\phi(3^a)$ ever gives $26$.

Answer (score 1):

If $n=\smash{\displaystyle\prod_{i=1}^r p_i^{e_i}}$, then $$\varphi(n)=\smash{\prod_{i=1}^r p_i^{e_i-1}}(p_i-1).$$.
The only factors of $n$ that might end up in $\varphi(n)$ divisible by $13$ are $13^e$ for some $e\ge 1$. However $13^e$ can't be a factor, as it would give a contribution of $13^{e-1}\cdot 12$.

Answer (score 1):

Because 26 is what is called a "nontotient." With only two exceptions, $\phi(n)$ is never odd. There are also some even values that never occur as $\phi(n)$, and 26 is one of them.

Remember that $\phi(p) = p - 1$ if $p$ is prime. But $27 = 3^3$, so 26 is not a totient this way. How about $\phi(p^\alpha) = (p - 1)p^{\alpha - 1}$? Or some combination of primes and powers of primes? Since $26 = 2 \times 13$, we're looking for $n$ a multiple of 3 or 4. But what to make of the 13? If you're still not convinced, you can try testing  $\phi(n)$ for $26 < n < 162$ by brute force, e.g., `Select[Range[27, 161], EulerPhi[#] == 26 &]`.

So, if $\phi(n) = 26$ has no solution, then $\phi(\phi(n)) = 26$ is absolutely hopeless.

Comment: For the upper limit on brute force, $3\times 14\times 2=84$ would be big enough. A given number $n$ can't possibly be totient for any number bigger than taking each of its prime factors, adding one to each, multiplying back together and doubling. No doubt a more sophisticated analysis could get a lower number for that upper limit too.

Comment: Quite true. But if the asker has access to Mathematica, it wouldn't hurt any to have it go up to $10^3$, which we both know to be excessive.

Comment: Also true ;-). I guess I was just curious how you selected 162...

Comment: I think I did $27 \times 6$. Really just a guess at the upper bound.